# Is the first element of a sequence mandatory regardless of the min/max occurs?

Tags: xml, xsd

It seems our XML will not validate against the XSD, my question here, is the first element of a sequence always mandatory or is there anything else which makes the element mandatory?

XML which will generate error:

```
            <CustomProperty>
                <ID>Sustainable option</ID>
                <Value>
                    <DataType>decimal</DataType>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>n/a</UnitOfMeasure>
                </Value>
            </CustomProperty>
```

against XSD:

```
  <xs:element name="ValueString" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="DataType" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="UnitOfMeasure" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="CustomProperty">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Value">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="ValueString" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="DataType" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="UnitOfMeasure" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

if we add the element (empty or filled)  as in per below sample it seems to be valid against the XSD

```
        <CustomProperty>
            <ID>Sustainable option</ID>
            <Value>
                <ValueString>2</ValueString>
                <DataType>decimal</DataType>
                <UnitOfMeasure>n/a</UnitOfMeasure>
            </Value>
```

also valid:

```
            <ID>Sustainable option</ID>
            <Value>
                <ValueString />
                <DataType>decimal</DataType>
                <UnitOfMeasure>n/a</UnitOfMeasure>
            </Value>
```

From the XSD I understood that  is optional.

Comment: So which parser or tool do you use, which error message exactly do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You say "It seems our XML will not validate against the XSD".

However, the XML shown is valid against the supplied XSD, so there is something else going on here.

You need to tell us more precisely what you are doing (including what products you are using and how you are invoking them) and more precisely how it is failing.